# How to have excel paste a value in a specific cell according to another data table

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, cells

I'm working with excel 2010,

I have an excel sheet with two tables. The primary table contains a calender and each calender day has a specific numeric value in the cell below the date.

The numeric values of the second table are entirely dependant of the value of its master cell which is H 18. So the only important cell here is H18. Above cell H18 is another cell (F13) containing another date.

[image]

The goal is to be able to change the date in cell F13 and that the data belonging to this date written in the calender will be copied automatically into cell H18.

Comment: What have you attempted so far? Did you get stuck with something?

Comment: I have tried the research formula, but I'm not really sure how to apply this here...

Comment: Can you add the formula you've [found to your post please](http://superuser.com/posts/717985/edit)

Comment: I did not find a specific formula yet. Thank you for any effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [HLOOKUP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/hlookup-HP005209114.aspx)

H18 `=HLOOKUP($F$13,$D$6:$Q$7,2,0)`

Change the D6:Q7 to wherever your first table ends.

Comment: Thank you! My table ends at AG so my formula would be 

=HLOOKUP($F$13,$D$6:$AG$7,2,0)

But it does not seem toaccept it...can you see a mistake?

Comment: =HLOOKUP($F$13,$D$6:$Q$7,2,1)

Got it! THANKS A MILLION!!!

Comment: Using a `1` at the end is like using a `true` and it will not always look for the exact value. The 0 `false` is a better method

Comment: That's right! Thx!